# Clear text authentication in ETL tools

Tags: mysql, pentaho, talend

I am trying to implement some ETL processes by testing Pentaho & Talend. We are using a MySQL database, where we connect with a Clear Text Authentication.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cleartext-authentication-plugin.html

I cannot find any plugin or module for neither PDI or Talend that uses this type of authentications. Has anyone worked with something similar and has any workaround on it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll leave aside the fact that this doesn't sound very secure. Maybe you have a good reason for doing it this way that I'm not aware of.

In the `tMySQLOutput` component, go to the `Advanced settings` tab, and add the following in the `Additional JDBC parameters`:`"authenticationPlugins=mysql_clear_password"`  (with quotes).

(note: I'm not sure if the parameter value has the right syntax. You might have to do some more digging to find out)

Rationale:

1) The link you sent has this line:

> The mysql, mysqladmin, and mysqlslap client programs support an --enable-cleartext-plugin option that enables the plugin on a per-invocation basis.

2) The `tMySQLOutput` allows custom parameters to be sent to the JDBC library. See here for details: https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tMysqlOutput .

3) MySQL's JDBC library has an authentication plug-in parameter. See here for details: (scroll down to the list of parameters) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: Thanks Maira, that's very helpful :)